# How to improve values annotation on sns.lineplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, plot-annotations

I've got this data:

|  | mentor_cnt | mentee_cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 3 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 2 | 7 | 7 |
| 3 | 18 | 19 |
| 4 | 24 | 27 |
| 5 | 37 | 35 |
| 6 | 53 | 56 |
| 7 | 63 | 70 |
| 8 | 86 | 89 |
| 9 | 102 | 114 |
| 10 | 135 | 149 |
| 11 | 154 | 169 |
| 12 | 174 | 202 |
| 13 | 232 | 287 |
| 14 | 298 | 386 |
| 15 | 343 | 475 |
| 16 | 384 | 552 |
| 17 | 446 | 684 |
| 18 | 509 | 883 |
| 19 | 469 | 757 |

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('darkgrid')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.lineplot(x=df['month'], y=df['mentor_cnt'], color = 'b', label='Mentors', markers=True, marker='o')
sns.lineplot(x=df['month'], y=df['mentee_cnt'], color = 'r', label='Mentee', markers=True, marker='o')
plt.ylim(min(df['mentee_cnt'])-60, max(df['mentee_cnt'])+50)
columns =['mentor_cnt', 'mentee_cnt']
colors = ['b', 'w']
facecolors = ['none', 'r']
x_position = [0, -10]
y_position = [-18, 5]

for col, fc, c, x_p, y_p in zip(columns, facecolors, colors, x_position, y_position):
    for x, y in zip(df['month'], df[col]):
        label = '{:.0f}'.format(y)
        plt.annotate(
            label,
            (x, y),
            textcoords='offset points',
            xytext=(x_p, y_p),
            ha='center',
            color=c
        ).set_bbox(dict(facecolor=fc, alpha=0.5, boxstyle='round', edgecolor='none'))
ax.legend()
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Number of persons')
plt.title('Mentee, mentor')
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: plt.show]

Line with mentors looks fine for me, but I can't figure out how to make values for mentee looks better.
Is there any way to set  best positions of values automatically?
With set_bbox I tried to make it readable, but I think it's look terrible.

I improved my graph this way, maybe it'll help someone (thx to trenton-mckinney):

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.lineplot(x=df['month'], y=df['mentor_cnt'], color='b', label='Mentors', markers=True, marker='o')
sns.lineplot(x=df['month'], y=df['mentee_cnt'], color='r', label='Mentee', markers=True, marker='o')
plt.ylim(min(df['mentee_cnt'])-60, max(df['mentee_cnt'])+50)
columns = ['mentor_cnt', 'mentee_cnt']
colors = ['b', 'r']
facecolors = ['none', 'r']
x_position = [0, -15]
y_position = [-18, 3]

for col, fc, c, x_p, y_p in zip(columns, facecolors, colors, x_position, y_position):
    for x, y in zip(df['month'], df[col]):
        # describe_nearest - list with quantiles for data
        lst = [0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]
        describe_nearest = []
        [describe_nearest.append(df[col].quantile(el, interpolation='nearest')) for el in lst]
        describe_nearest.append(df[col].values[-1::][0])
        # add annotation if value in quantiles list
        if y in describe_nearest:
            label = '{:.0f}'.format(y)
            plt.annotate(
                label,
                (x, y),
                textcoords='offset points',
                xytext=(x_p, y_p),
                ha='center',
                color=c
            )
ax.legend()
plt.xlabel('Month')
plt.ylabel('Number of persons')
plt.title('Mentee, mentor')
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: new output]

Comment: [Automatic label placement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_label_placement) **Automatic text placement is one of the most difficult, complex, and time-consuming problems...**

Comment: So it's much easier to leave the graph as it is?

Comment: I'd say it's not necessary to place any annotations. It makes the visualization messy. If you're going to annotate anything, annotate something that you really want the audience to know, such as the peak values.

Comment: That's make sense. How can I do this?

Comment: Additionally, this appears to be discrete data, so a bar plot might be better. See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwpdF.png)

Comment: Find the `.max` for each column, and then annotate that point

Comment: [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vXYQ.png) with dates.

Comment: I've just make list with quantiles (nearest) for any columns and annotate this values. =) Thx for help.